# Best approach to caching geocoded results

Tags: database, google-maps-api-3, geocoding

We have a database with roughly 1.5 million rows, soon to be closer to 3 million. Each row has an address. Our service is responsible for visualizing each row on a map in several ways. The issue is that many times, each map will have well over a thousand different rows being displayed. Because of that, it is impractical to have the client (or the server) load all 1000 coordinates from something such as Google Maps API v3.

Ideally, we'd like to store the coordinate values into the table so they are ready for use whenever. However, rate limiting would make that take months to successfully cache all the data.

Is there a service that has no limit, or maybe allows for multiple addresses to be sent at a time to expedite the process?

Comment: Are your addresses in the US? If not, which countries? (Only a handful of countries have address-level geocoding.)

Comment: Yes the addresses are in the US. There may be a few rows that reference other countries but we can ignore them for now.

Comment: And I should mention that if it makes a significant difference, Zip codes or Cities can be used instead of the full address. The greater accuracy would be nice but beggars can't be choosers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try LiveAddress by [SmartyStreets](http://smartystreets.com) -- the addresses will not only be geocoded but also verified. (Though, you won't get geocoding results for addresses which don't verify.)

You could upload a list with all your addresses or process them through our API. (If your addresses aren't split into components, you'll need to use the API for now, which can receive 100 addresses per request.) Granted, for 1 million+ rows, it's not free (unless you're a non-profit or educational), but the service scales in the cloud and can handle thousands of addresses per second. There are plans which fit millions of lookups, all the way to just plain Unlimited. (By the way, I work at SmartyStreets.)

Most addresses have "Zip9" precision (meaning, the coordinates are accurate to the 9-digit ZIP code level, which is like block-level). Some are Zip7 or Zip5 which are less accurate but might be good enough for your needs.

If you need to arrange precision skydiving, though, you might consider a more dedicated mapping service that gives you rooftop-level precision and allows you to store the data. I know that you can store and cache SmartyStreets data, but map services have different restrictions. For example, Google has rooftop-level data for most US addresses, and lets you cache their data to improve performance, but you aren't allowed to store it in a database and build your own data set. You could also pay Google to raise your rate limits, though it's a little pricey.

I'm not sure what terms the other mapping providers have. (Geocoding services like [TAMU](http://geoservices.tamu.edu/Services/Geocode/) have better accuracy but less capable infrastructure, thus rate limits, although you can probably pay to have those raised or lifted.)